# Reducing code by removing duplication in codes with a function?

Tags: python, function

I have asked to reduce the code to removing duplication :

```
june_hours = 243
june_cost = june_hours * 0.65
print("In June we spent: " + str(june_cost))

july_hours = 325
july_cost = july_hours * 0.65
print("In July we spent: " + str(july_cost))

august_hours = 298
august_cost = august_hours * 0.65
print("In August we spent: " + str(august_cost))
```

I tried to :

```
def print_monthly_expense(month, hours):
    time = hours * 0.65
    print("In " + month + " We spent : " + str(time))

print_monthly_expense("June",243)
print_monthly_expense("July",325)
print_monthly_expense("August",298)
```

And the result is :

> > > In June We spent : 157.95000000000002
> > >       In July We spent : 211.25
> > >       In August We spent : 193.70000000000002

And the system replied :

> > > Not quite. Let your function do most of the work and just
> > >       pass the name of the month and the associated hours as
> > >       parameters.
> > >
> > > Remember for June, July and August the hours
> > >       are 243, 325 and 298 respectively.

Please help me, whats wrong with the code?

thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that the system is expecting those exact numbers. Call `str(int(time))` to round them properly.

Comment: Please explain your expected outputs, without simply quoting "the reply of the system". It is not crystal clear.

Comment: What is the "system" that replied? Your function looks okay to me and it prints the same values as the original code. For the weird floating points see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I don't know the expected output, but with this output the system is not satisfied.

Comment: Please see the original codes, which needs to be shorten as possible. Anyone have better suggestions than what I did, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Monirul, looks like we're both working on the same thing.  I had the same error you had when I first ran my code.

I had this code at first:

```
def print_monthly_expense(month, hours):
    cost = (hours) * 0.67
    print("In "  + month + " we spent: " + str(cost))

print_monthly_expense("June",243)
print_monthly_expense("July",325)
print_monthly_expense("August",298)
```

The first few times I got ran it, I got the same error you had and I couldn't figure it out.  Then I realized the 0.67 was wrong, I should have used 0.65.  When I fixed the error, the code ran correctly and I got this message.

```
Here is your output:
In June we spent: 157.95000000000002
In July we spent: 211.25
In August we spent: 193.70000000000002

Nice work! You're getting acquainted with some interesting
coding practices to reduce code duplication.
```

Did you figure out what was wrong?  Maybe it's the text formatting? You have upper case "We" and a space before the colon at the end "spent :"?  Just guessing, I don't see anything else.

Comment: it would be more helpful to show the working code in the answer, with a comment in that code indicating the correction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, may be you are right! I will try.